# Is this a sufficient self-study method for baby rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I have been self studying baby rudin.

I have limited time, so I’ve  settled upon the following study method:

Every time I encounter a theorem, I don’t move on until I prove it myself. However, I have been skipping the exercises. I figured if the exercises theorems were as important as the chapter theorems, they would have been included in the chapter.

Is this method sufficient to capture the essence of the book?

Comment: No. Working exercises and writing proofs of related results are both absolutely essential for learning mathematics.

Comment: @TedShifrin could you expand a bit more? In particular, why does proving a chapter theorem not count as working an exercise? Why are they not interchangeable? How do they differ?

Comment: You should probably avoid Rudin, as his intended audience is more those who have studied real analysis but want a refresher. You'd probably find Tao or Abbott more suitable.

Comment: Doing exercises helps you in many ways. Some examples: helping you learn *when* to use the theorems; training your intuitions in the math you are learning; and teaching you solution techniques and ideas that might not be present in the chapter's examples.

Comment: Do the exercises even if you can prove the theorems yourself.  Plus you may soon enough find you can't prove some of them yourself without peeking :-).  I remember doing a lot of exercises in Topology by Willard in school and it was very helpful (plus it was assigned HW).

Comment: Rudin is not a good book for self-study. I taught once using it, as it had been used for many years at my institution. Then I understood it is really bad, just a bunch of definitions followed by theorems, without any motivation or insight or application or life in it. You can use it to feed your fireplace.  Try Abbott, or Pugh, or Zorich. Those have nice exercises you should definitely work on.